# windows 8 phone development possible under windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

is it possible to develop windows 8 phone applications in windows 7 with vs.net 2010?

Or do I need to upgrade to windows 8 altogether?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Windows Phone 8 development possible under windows 7?

No, Windows 8 64-bit and Visual Studio 2012 are required.
Windows 8 Pro is also required to run the emulator (along with a processor that supports SLAT).

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the installation files to allow it to be installed on Windows 7.
Here are the modified setup files for WP8 SDK 9900:

1. Run `InstallWP8SDK.bat` to start the installation!
2. Download: http://www5.zippyshare.com/v/67777536/file.html

Have fun developing on the good old Windows 7.